# AzCopy Sync command is failing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I'm issuing this command:

```
azcopy sync "D:\Releases\Test\MyApp" "http://server3:10000/devstoreaccount1/myapp?sv=2019-02-02&st=2020-06-24T03%3A19%3A44Z&se=2020-06-25T03%3A19%3A44Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=REDACTED"
```

...and I'm getting this error:

> error parsing the input given by the user. Failed with error Unable to infer the source 'D:\Releases\Test\MyApp' / destination 'http://server3:10000/devstoreaccount1/myapp?sv=2019-02-02&st=2020-06-24T03%3A19%3A44Z&se=2020-06-25T03%3A19%3A44Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=-REDACTED-

I would have thought my source was pretty clear.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Not sure, why your question was downvoted 

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering the same thing. I've long been frustrated by downvoters who refuse to leave a comment as to why. I call them drive-by downvotes. They're counter-productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have run into an issue with azcopy that it does not support local emulator (at least for sync command). There's an open issue on Github for the same: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/554.

Basically the issue is coming from the following lines of [`code`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/92eafc2923c2cdc1e8d0528166aaff7ba1ff7f6b/cmd/validators.go#L123-155), where it returns location as `Unknown` in case of storage emulator URLs:

```
func inferArgumentLocation(arg string) common.Location {
    if arg == pipeLocation {
        return common.ELocation.Pipe()
    }
    if startsWith(arg, "http") {
        // Let's try to parse the argument as a URL
        u, err := url.Parse(arg)
        // NOTE: sometimes, a local path can also be parsed as a url. To avoid thinking it's a URL, check Scheme, Host, and Path
        if err == nil && u.Scheme != "" && u.Host != "" {
            // Is the argument a URL to blob storage?
            switch host := strings.ToLower(u.Host); true {
            // Azure Stack does not have the core.windows.net
            case strings.Contains(host, ".blob"):
                return common.ELocation.Blob()
            case strings.Contains(host, ".file"):
                return common.ELocation.File()
            case strings.Contains(host, ".dfs"):
                return common.ELocation.BlobFS()
            case strings.Contains(host, benchmarkSourceHost):
                return common.ELocation.Benchmark()
                // enable targeting an emulator/stack
            case IPv4Regex.MatchString(host):
                return common.ELocation.Unknown()//This is what gets returned in case of storage emulator URL.
            }

            if common.IsS3URL(*u) {
                return common.ELocation.S3()
            }
        }
    }

    return common.ELocation.Local()
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm starting to wonder whether I might have better luck with [Azurite](https://github.com/azure/azurite).

Comment: Nope. It’s not the problem with the emulator. It’s an issue with azcopy tool. You can try older version of azcopy, Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell Cmdlets.

Comment: Would you happen to know whether those cmdlets contain a sync functionality? True, I could roll my own, but it'd be handy if it already existed in parity with AzCopy.

Comment: I don't think so. azcopy sync is a one way sync and not a bidirectional one. So if your objective is to upload data from local to blob, then the Cmdlet would work just fine. From azcopy sync documentation page: `Replicates the source location to the destination location`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For a moment I was hopeful that [AzureCLI](https://dev.to/codepossible/using-azure-cli-with-local-storage-emulator-40i8) might be the solution, but it turns out that AzureCLI uses AzCopy under the hood. So it seems we're dead in the water on this for now. Network shares it is. Primitive, yes, but functional.

Comment: p.s. Good find, digging up that snippet. I've added it to the issue you linked.

Comment: I managed to get this working—see my answer below. (I also credited you in your linked issue for finding the snippet. Thanks.)

Comment: Awesome! I’m glad to see that you’re unblocked.

Comment: And what a block it was! Three full days on that thing :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when trying to do a sync from my local machine to Azure Blob storage.

This was the command I was running:

```
azcopy sync "C:\AzureStorageTest\my-app\*" "https://myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net/$web"
```

But I got the error below:

> INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: 'c:\AzureStorageTest\my-app' of type Local, and Destination: 'https://
> myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net/' of type Local

> INFO: Based on the parameters supplied, a valid source-destination combination could not automatically be found. Please
> check the parameters you supplied.  If they are correct, please specify an exact source and destination type using the -
> -from-to switch. Valid values are two-word phases of the form BlobLocal, LocalBlob etc.  Use the word 'Blob' for Blob St
> orage, 'Local' for the local file system, 'File' for Azure Files, and 'BlobFS' for ADLS Gen2. If you need a combination
> that is not supported yet, please log an issue on the AzCopy GitHub issues list.

> error parsing the input given by the user. Failed with error Unable to infer the source 'C:\AzureStorageTest\my-app'
> / destination 'https://myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net.z16.web.core.windows.net/'.
> PS C:\Users\promise> azcopy sync "C:\AzureStorageTest\my-app" "https://myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net.z16.web.core.window
> s.net/$web" -from-to localblob
> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -from-to

**Here's how I solved it**:

I was missing the `?[SAS]` argument at the end of the Blob storage location. Also, as of this writing, the `azccopy sync` command does not seem to support the `--from-to switch`. So instead of this:

```
azcopy sync "C:\AzureStorageTest\my-app" "https://myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net/$web"
```

I had this:

```
azcopy sync "C:\AzureStorageTest\my-app" "https://myapptest.blob.core.windows.net/%24web?[SAS]" --recursive
```

**Note**:

1. The format is `azcopy sync "/path/to/dir" "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/directory]?[SAS]" --recursive`. You only need to modify the `"/path/to/dir"`, `[account]` and `[container]/[path/to/directory]`. Every other thing remains the way it is.
2. My actual Blob storage location is https://myapptest.blob.core.windows.net/$24web but I used https://myapptest.blob.core.windows.net/%24web, since `$` will throw some error when used, so `%24` was used.
3. Don't use the blob website address like I did which is `https://myapptest.z16.web.core.windows.net/` that got me frustrated with lots of errrors, rather use the blob storage address `https://myapptest.blob.core.windows.net`
4. The `--recursive` flag is already inferred in this directory sync operation, so you may consider leaving it out. I put it though for clarity sake.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 1):

OK—after much futzing I was finally able to get this to work, using Azurite and PowerShell. It's clear that neither AzureCLI nor AzCopy are well-tested under emulation.

Here's a rough-and-tumble script that can be called from a pipeline:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $Container,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $Source
)

$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -Local
$BlobNames = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $Context -Container $Container | % { $_.Name }
$FilesToSync = gci $Source\* -Include RELEASES, Setup.exe
$Packages = gci $Source -Filter *.nupkg

$Packages | % {
  If (!($BlobNames.Contains($_.Name))) {
    $FilesToSync += $_
  }
}

$FilesToSync | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container $Container -Force
```

Note that this is highly customized for my [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) deployments (*.nupkg, RELEASES, Setup.exe), so a person will want to adjust accordingly for his own environment.

Azurite can be set to always-on using a Scheduled Task to run this command every hour:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process azurite-blob.cmd -PassThru -ArgumentList '--blobHost 0.0.0.0'"
```

The argument sets Azurite to listen on any IP so that it can be reached from other computers on the network. I punched a hole in the firewall for ports 10000-10002.

Be careful to set the Task to run under the same account that was used to install Azurite, otherwise the Task won't be able to see `azurite-blob.cmd` (it's in `%AppData%\npm`, which is added to `PATH` during installation).

Answer (score 0):

The command line needs the --recursive option. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error when using the `--recursive` switch.

Comment: I think the /destination is not needed.

Comment: Hm, I'm not following you... I'm not using `/destination` anywhere in my command syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your edit to redact the sig, BTW. This is a local instance so I figured it wouldn't matter, but caution is the better part of valor in any case.

Comment: Anyway—I'm beat for the day. I'll pick it up again tomorrow. I'll try testing with a real-live storage account. That may be the problem. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1031), where he's trying to do the same thing. It might be a bug.